# Access and load a PDF from Storage into Browser in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to access and load a PDF in the browser using Laravel for the first time.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have the following route in my web.php:

```
    use Illuminate\Http\Response;

    Route::get('public/downloads/{pathToFile}', function ($pathToFile) {
    return response()->file($pathToFile);
    });
```

I have the following in my view:

```
             <a class='col-6' href="/downloads/{{ asset('public/storage/' 
   . $plansubmission->current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1)  }}">{{ 
    asset('storage/' . $plansubmission- 
   >current_plan_year_claims_data_file_1)  }}</a>
```

Comment: I think if the file is already public, you does not need the route. What you got when click on the link?

Comment: Thanks. I got a 404 even though it was in the right location.

I refactored and now just trying to figure out how to chain a variable onto a URL in my controller.  Tried everything:

  $pathToFile=public_path(). "\storage\ $id";

Comment: Where in your project folders is the file?

Comment: Hey Alexander, welcome to SO! I'm assuming you've [read the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem) on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**From the docs:**](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) *The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in **storage/app/public.***

This is assuming you have created a symbolic link by running `php artisan storage:link`. Otherwise, you might need to tweak this for wherever you are storing the PDF, but I think this approach accomplishes what you're after.

**Routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/public/download/{filename}', 'PdfController@download')->name('download.pdf');
```

**PdfController**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

/**
* Display a PDF directly in the browser
*
* @param $filename <-- the filename we want
*
* @return Response
**/

public function download($filename)
{
    $url = $filename.'.pdf';

    if( $this->storageObjectExists('public', $url) == true ) // Does this file exist?
    {
        return response()->file($url); // <-- display file directly in browser

    } else {

        return back()->with('danger', 'No file located!'); // Let the user know
    }

}


/**
* Determine if a particular file exists on a disk
*
* @param $disk <-- 'local', 'azure', 'aws', etc
* @param $url <-- /path/to/file.pdf
*
* @return boolean 
**/
public function storageObjectExists($disk, $url)
{
    $exists = Storage::disk($disk)->exists($url);

    return $exists;
}
```

**Form.blade.php**

```
<!-- optional warning for user --> 
@if(session('danger')) 
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <p>{{ session('danger') }}</p>
    </div>
@endif 

<a href="/public/download/{{ $filename }}">{{ $filename }}</a>
```